# OnTouchListener is not working, how to fix it?

Tags: java, android

Can Anyone help me? Why this code is not compiling? I have no idea..

```
   import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.view.MotionEvent;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       Button myButton;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tryButton);

       }

       myButton.setOnTouchListener(new onTouchListener() {
           public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event){
               return true;
           }
       }

       );
   }
```

setOnTouchListener is red for whole time.

> - Errors:
> - Error:(19, 32) error:  expected
> - Error:(19, 33) error: illegal start of type
> - Error:(19, 36) error: ')' expected
> - Error:(19, 52) error: ';' expected
> - Error:(19, 53) error: illegal start of type
> - Error:(25, 5) error: class, interface, or enum expected
> - Error:(26, 1) error: class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: It's very simple, you set `OnTouchListener` event out of your all methods.

Comment: You need to extend the `onCreate(...)` method's body to include the statement that sets the listener to the `myButton` button.

Answer (score 3):

```
   import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.view.MotionEvent;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       Button myButton;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tryButton);

           myButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
               @Override
               public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event){
                   return true;
               }
           });
       }
   }
```

You need to put it inside a method.

Comment: Ok I made it and there is still an error: Error:(19, 41) error: cannot find symbol class onTouchListener. I tried to use: implements onTouchListener but its still the same

Comment: please see the updated answer - "OnTouchListener" starts with a capital O